# Expected value of the indicator variable Z , E.M. - PRML

Tags: machine-learning

I am having a hard time figuring out the equation 9.39 page 443 in Bishop's book : Pattern recognition and Machine Learning.

A posterior distribution in the book is written as:
$$
p(\textbf{Z} \mid \textbf{X}, \mu, \pi) \approx \Pi_n \Pi_k [\pi_k \mathcal{N}(x_n \mid \mu_k, \Sigma_k)]^{z_{nk}} 
$$

where $z$ is a 1-of-K binary rperesentation in which a particular element $z_k \in \{0,1 \}$ and $\sum_k z_k=1$ and $z_{nk}$ denotes the indicator for the $n$th point.

Then the author states that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[z_{nk}] = \frac{\sum_{z_{nk}} z_{nk} [\pi_k \mathcal{N}(x_n \mid \mu_k, \Sigma_k)]^{z_{nk}}}{\sum_{z_{nj}} [\pi_j \mathcal{N}(x_n \mid \mu_j, \Sigma_j)]^{z_{nj}}}
$$

I don't really understand where this expression comes from. This is not the classical definition of the expectation of a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
  p(Z\mid X,\mu,\Sigma,\pi)\propto \prod_{n=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^K \left\{\pi_k\cdot\mathrm{N}(x_n\mid \mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right\}^{z_{nk}}
$$
factors over $n$, the $z_n$'s are conditionally independent and
$$
  p(z_n\mid x_n,\mu,\Sigma,\pi)\propto \prod_{k=1}^K \left\{\pi_k\cdot\mathrm{N}(x_n\mid \mu_k,\Sigma_k)\right\}^{z_{nk}}.
$$
Now, $z_{nk}=1$ if and only if $z_{n\ell}=0$ for $\ell\neq k$. Hence,
$$
  p(z_{nk} = 1\mid x_n,\mu,\Sigma,\pi) =\frac{\pi_k\cdot\mathrm{N}(x_n\mid \mu_k,\Sigma_k)}{\sum_{\ell=1}^K \left\{\pi_\ell\cdot\mathrm{N}(x_n\mid \mu_\ell,\Sigma_\ell)\right\}^\ell} = (*).
$$
Since $z_{nk}$ is an indicator, the expectation
$$
  \mathbb{E}[z_{nk}\mid x_n,\mu,\Sigma,\pi]=(*).
$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand before the last line and the last line. It is because if I expand the expectation formula $\mathbb{E}[z_{nk}] = 1 * p(z_{nk}=1 \mid x_n, \mu, \Sigma, \pi) + 0 * p(z_{nk}=0\mid x_n, \mu, \Sigma, \pi)$ ?

Comment: Exactly. Perfect.