# Expectation with respect to a product distribution

Tags: distributions, random-variable, expected-value, independence

Let $\theta \in \Theta$ be a $d-$dimensional random variable.

Let $q$ be a distribution on $\Theta$ of the form $$q(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^d q_i (\theta_i).$$
In other words $q$ is a product of marginals.

**How can I express $\mathbb{E}_q[f(\theta)]$?**

This would be $\int_\Theta f(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^d q_i (\theta_i) d\theta$. Is there some way to factorize this? If that's not possible, how about for $f(\theta) = \theta$?

**Edit:**  if $f(\theta)=\theta$,

$$\mathbb{E}_q[\theta] = \int \theta \prod_{i=1}^d q_i (\theta_i) d\theta$$

We could consider that integral componentwise, where the $i$th component can be written
$$\int \theta_i q_i(\theta_i) d\theta_i \prod_{j \neq i} q_j(\theta_j) d\theta_j.$$

I don't know what to do with $\prod_{j \neq i} q_j(\theta_j) d\theta_j$. (Ideally it would disappear). The only reason I could think of is that $\int \prod_j q_j d\theta_j = \prod_j \int q_j d\theta_j = 1$, but you generally can't move the product out of the integral, right?

Comment: There is no general closed-form solution for this integral even though the components $\theta_i$ are independent. In the case when $f(\theta)=\theta$, $\mathbb E_q[\theta_i] = \int \theta_i q_i(\theta_i)\text d\theta_i$.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks! that makes sense, but I can't seem to derive it. Editing my post now, could you let me know what step I'm missing?

Comment: If you are struggling with the derivation of what Xi'an has specified, I have derived what you are looking for in the answer [*Explain the expected value of an indicator variable in section 9.3.1 of PRML"*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/explain-the-expected-value-of-an-indicator-variable-in-section-9-3-1-of-prml/511163#511163) under *"Further derivation of (1) with respect to comments."*.

Comment: @microhaus ah yes, thank you! So is it fair to say $\int \prod_j q_j d\theta_j = \prod_j \int q_j d\theta_j = 1$ because all the $\theta_j$'s are from different dimensions?

Comment: Just realised the derivation I linked to was in the case where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Please may you clarify the nature of $f$ in your example? In particular, is it the case that $f$ is vector-valued i.e. $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: @microhaus In my case $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is there anything that can simplify calculations?

Comment: The derivation I linked and what I think Xi'an has specified applies in the case where $f$ can be applied element-wise to every element of the $d$-dimensional column vector $\theta$. Because in that case, the idea of $q(\theta)$ factorising into $d$ independent marginals $q_i(\theta_i)$ for each component is natural. However, in the case where $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so that $f$ does not act element-wise, then I'm not sure how you could make any use of $q(\theta) = \prod^d_{i=1} q_i(\theta_i)$ to simplify further. Am I making sense to you?

Comment: @microhaus yup makes sense… f can combine the elements of $\theta$ in a way that’s not factorable